# Clip parts of a tensor

Tags: theano

I have a theano tensor and I would like to clip its values, but each index to a different range.

For example, if I have a vector [a,b,c] , I want to clip a to [0,1] , clip b to [2,3] and c to [3,5].

How can I do that efficiently?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `theano.tensor.clip` operation supports symbolic minimum and maximum values so you can pass three tensors, all of the same shape, and it will perform an element-wise clip of the first with respect to the second (minimum) and third (maximum).

This code shows two variations on this theme. `v1` requires the minimum and maximum values to be passed as separate vectors while `v2` allows the minimum and maximum values to be passed more like a list of pairs, represented as a two column matrix.

```
import theano
import theano.tensor as tt


def v1():
    x = tt.vector()
    min_x = tt.vector()
    max_x = tt.vector()
    y = tt.clip(x, min_x, max_x)
    f = theano.function([x, min_x, max_x], outputs=y)
    print f([2, 1, 4], [0, 2, 3], [1, 3, 5])


def v2():
    x = tt.vector()
    min_max = tt.matrix()
    y = tt.clip(x, min_max[:, 0], min_max[:, 1])
    f = theano.function([x, min_max], outputs=y)
    print f([2, 1, 4], [[0, 1], [2, 3], [3, 5]])


def main():
    v1()
    v2()


main()
```